# Unable to post any comments, getting a websocket error

Tags: bug, comments, web-sockets

I am unable to post any comments, and am getting a websocket error instead.
The error in my console is:

> The connection to ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading.

This prevents me from adding a comment, and this error is also thrown for other things such as up and down votes.

My browser: Latest Firefox 20 on OS/X 10.8

Disabling noscript had no effect.

**EDIT** Sorry, I can't comment at the moment, so I will respond here. Indeed it's still a beta build, but I figured I would still want to make SO aware of this. It could become a problem once it is released.

Comment: Firefox 20.0 is not due to be officially released until [March 26, 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_release_history). If you're on a nightly build, I would refer the fault to the Firefox dev channel

Comment: Currently, I am behind a firewall that blocks web sockets, and I can still comment normally (FF 19). I am not sure what causes your problem, but likely related to the fact that you are using FF20.